# iOS 6 - Error in sending data in HTTPBody with POST method

Tags: ios6, http-post, http-status-code-400

Till last night the code was working perfectly, but today i am facing a weird problem.

```
NSString *hostStr = [@"My API string" stringByAppendingString: @"/users/login"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"-----FOO";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *usernameData = [username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSData *passwordData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data[login_name]\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:usernameData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data[password]\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:passwordData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",serverOutput);
```

Above code gives me following response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at MY API URL Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

But for the same lines of code when i comment this part

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data[login_name]\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:usernameData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data[password]\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:passwordData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

It gives me following request response

```
{"login_name":"Username or Password is not valid","responseCode":"0"}
```

Means when i am not sending any data in HTTPBody, API call gives me desire response.
I have no any idea what is going wrong here. Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. This is something that I never realized could be a problem.

As I more and more check my code, I found that there isn't any problem with my code up "there". But the problem was server side.

I contacted the server people and they said that they have enabled some ModSecurity so a multipart form data was not able to be sent in the HTTPBody.

This cost me two whole days to figure out. Hope it saves some one's time.